# jQuery function if Bootstrap tab shown, set value to input, different for each tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, tabs

I have five different Bootstrap tabs. I was wondering if it is possible to update a input field, which is located beneath tab, with some value depending on which tab is currently showing.

I have tried something with:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {

})
```

which is in twitter documentation, but I did not succeeded, and honestly I don't have a idea if something like that is even possible...

for example if the first tab is displayed, input gets value 1, if second is displayed, input gets 2 etc...

And I do not want to solve it with on click to tab navigation, In my project tabs, navigation is not shown in that way...

here is jsfiddle that you can edit: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/3mLF3/

html:

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four" data-toggle="tab">Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#five" data-toggle="tab">Five</a></li>
        </ul>
     <ul class="tab-content">
          <li class="tab-pane fade in active" id="one">
           first
         </li>
          <li class="tab-pane fade in" id="two">
           second                  
         </li>
          <li class="tab-pane fade in" id="three">
             third     
         </li>
          <li class="tab-pane fade in" id="four">
             fourth     
         </li>
          <li class="tab-pane fade in" id="five">
              fifth
          </li>
     </ul>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="span2" id="number" name="number">
</diV>
```

jquery, so far nothing:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
  //???
})
```

any idea is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself...added class to every `a` and then

```
    $('.one-tab').on('shown', function (e) {
                 $('#number').val('1');
            });
```

and so on....

thanks for help anyway